# Rails 4 Strong Parameters access attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.1

For rails 4 Strong Parameters I need to access two of the fields. How can I do that?

```
 def branch_params
   params.require(:branch).permit( :equal_number, :equal_main_branch_number, 
                                   :history, :inquiry_email, :internal_notes,
                                   :is_main_branch, :main_branch_number, :name,                
                                   :number,:region_id, :serving )
 end
```

I understand this part. [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

```
def create
  @branch = Branch.new(branch_params)
end
```

Now I need to pass two of the fields to pass into a method.

```
 format_branch_number(:equal_number, :equal_main_branch_number)
```

Comment: do you need to access these fields before Branch.new() or after?

Comment: In a different method all together. before then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs

> Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model
>   mass assignments until they have been whitelisted

what means, you cant use them to create AR object, but you can still use your params to do some stuff with them, so you can simply `format_branch_number(params[:equal_number], params[:equal_main_branch_number])`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
format_branch_number(params[:branch][:equal_number], params[:branch][:equal_main_branch_number])
```